# Querying Opportunities related to a contact return only Open Opportunities

Tags: soql, opportunitycontactrole, subquery

I am doing subquery Of Opportunities on Contact as follows:-

```
Select id,(select id from Opportunities) from Contact where id in (select ContactId from OpportunityContactRole)
```

I know this will return those Contacts which have at least one related opportunity. But what I can see, Those Opportunities which are Closed are not coming in the result but ContactId is coming.

Later, I found this is happening for those Opportunities whose contact roles have not checked for primary=true.

Can You make me understand this behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

My answer for your question:
I think/suspect that the sub-query from contact to child opportunities requires isPrimary on the OpportunityContactRole for that downwards traversal.

As a side note, If you later decide that you want to query all opportunities that have any opportunity contact role defined (regardless of isPrimary or not) then use `SELECT ID from Opportunity where ID IN (Select OpportunityID from OpportunityContactRole)`