# Make Opportunity SOQL subquery of Contacts return all opportunities in the contact's related list, not just primary ones?

Tags: soql, opportunity, contact, related-list, opportunitycontactrole

I have Contacts who are associated with multiple Opportunities via multiple `OpportunityContactRoles`. Some of those `OpportunityContactRoles` have `IsPrimary = true`; others don't. In the Lightning UI, in the Opportunity related list for those contacts, I get all the opportunities for which there is an `OpportunityContactRole`, whether it's primary or not. But when I look up the Contact via SOQL and include an Opportunity subquery, I only get the Opportunities whose `OpportunityContactRoles` are primary:

```sql
SELECT Id, (SELECT Id,Name FROM Opportunities) FROM Contact WHERE Id = '006F0000006B7fwAID'
```

I know from [a previous answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/231381/22141) that this is default SOQL behavior, but is there a way to force the SOQL above to return all Opportunities, whether or not their `OpportunityContactRoles` are primary? In other words, make it return all the opportunities I see in the Lightning UI? Seem fair to expect the UI and the SOQL to return the same thing.

Also, I know I can just add an `OpportunityContactRole` subquery, which would indeed return all Opportunities including non-primary ones, but they'll be wrapped in an `OpportunityContactRole` array, and the way our system is built, it's not an option to unpack that array without significant and ugly special-case modifications. I'm looking for an easier way.

Thanks all in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are right that using the `Opportunities` relationship on `Contact` you will only get the opportunity which has this contact as primary contact. This is enabled via `ContactId` field on the opportunity.

You will need to query on OpportunityContactRole using to get all opportunities.

`Select OpportunityId, Opportunity.Name, ContactId from OpportunityContactRole where Contactid = '006F0000006B7fwAID'`

Comment: Thanks for confirming my understanding. I need to get all opportunities by selecting from Contacts though. As I said in the question, I'm aware that I can select from OpportunityContactRole instead, but it's not an option for us.